# Render dynamic class value in MVC layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm having an MVC layout pages which looks roughly like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML
<html class="prod">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to render the value of class attribute (prod) dynamically based on something returned from my controller.

So far, I tried variations on the following without success

**Controller**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[AllowAnonymous]
public PartialViewResult Environment()
{
    return PartialView("Environment", "prod");
}
```

**View**

```
@model string 
@Model
```

**Layout**

```
<html class="@{ Html.RenderAction("Environment", "Site"); }">
```

This actually generates the following

```
<htmlprod class=""></htmlprod>
<html>
</html>
```

The same thing happens when I use a ContentResult. To be clear, I do not want to use a Viewbag.

I want to generate a raw HTML string and display that using a PartialView or something similar. The actual value is retrieved through a parameter in the constructor of the controller (ioc).

Comment: What's the issue with Viewbag out of curiosity?  Why is which environment in, something the controller has to know about?  That doesn't seem logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a partial to return you the class name. You may set the class name to the dynamic `ViewBag` dictionary and use that in your layout.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ViewBag.HtmlClass="prod";
  return View();
}
```

And in your Layout

```
<html class="@ViewBag.HtmlClass">

</html>
```

If you do not wish to use ViewBag, You can create a child action method which simply returns a string.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public string Environment()
{
    return "production";
}
```

And in your layout,

```
<html class="@Html.Action("Environment","Home")">
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't want to use the ViewBag. I specifically mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Also, as this is a layout page, I would have to add it to every action on every controller making it unfeasible.

Comment: Calling an action seems like a real expensive (creating a controller isn't trivial) way to do to this.

Answer (score 0):

You vague question seems to have some deficiencies.  Controllers shouldn't be in charge of what environment the application is executing in.  I would probably do:

Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  private const string Environment = "Environment";

  protected void Application_Start()
  {
    this.Application.SetEnvironment(Configuration.AppSettings[Environment]);
  }
}
```

HttpApplicationStateExtensions.cs

```
internal static HttpApplicationStateExtensions
{
  private const string Environment = "Environment";

  public static void SetEnvironment(this HttpApplicationState state,
    string environment)
  {
    state.Application[Environment] = environment;
  }
  public static string GetEnvironment(this HttpApplicationState state)
  {
    var result = state.Application[Environment];
    return result;
  }
}
```

WebViewPageExtensions.cs

```
internal static WebViewPageExtensions
{
  private const string Environment = "Environment";

  public static string GetEnvironment(this WebViewPage page)
  {
    var result = page.AppState[Environment];
    return result;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<html class="@GetEnvironemnt()">
</html>
```